# font-size gets ignored in some mobile-browsers, when adding: float:left

Tags: css, mobile, css-float

Do you know why the font-size of my links in my list gets ignored, when I put "float:left" to the list-elements?

Now the links are big, but after adding the float, they get small in the following mobile browsers: Firefox, Chrome, Opera. In Dolphin, Dolphin mini and Opera mini it is working and the links stay big (1.5em) after adding the float.

What is the reason for that and how can I get the links big in every mobile browser?

Here is the the link to my testcase without float:left: http://goo.gl/oB6FD3

Here is the the link to my testcase with float:left: http://goo.gl/zOujqP

And here is the code:

```
<head>
<style>
body {font-size: 100.01%; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
li {width: 5em; height: 3em;}
a {font-size: 1.5em;}
h1 {font-size: 1em;}
h2 {font-size: 1em;}
p {font-size: 1em;}
.clear {clear:both;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="...">One</a></li>
<li><a href="...">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="...">Three</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
<br />

<h1>h1 header</h1>                                      
<h2>h2 header</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</body>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could be the viewport the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding the media queries. Try to put the media queries and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because your using EM. Try using px. Different browsers have (including mobile) use a different font size by default, which is what EM is based off of.

Or, you could try changing your Body font to a px value.